# Filtering data without loops in R

Tags: r, loops, filtering, dataframe

I have quite big data frame (few millions of records).
I need to filter it due to following rule:
- For each product delete all records which are before the fifth record after the first record with x>0.

So, We are interested only in two columns - ID and x. Data frame is sorted by ID.
It is fairly easy to do it using loops, but loops doesn't perform well on such big data frame.

How to do it in 'vector style'?

**Example:**
BEFORE FILTERING

```
ID  x  
1 0  
1 0  
1 5  # First record with x>0  
1 0  
1 3  
1 4  
1 0   
1 9   
1 0  # Delete all earlier records of that product  
1 0  
1 6  
2 0  
2 1  # First record with x>0   
2 0  
2 4  
2 5  
2 8  
2 0  # Delete all earlier records of that product  
2 1  
2 3
```

After filtering:

```
ID  x  
1 9   
1 0  
1 0  
1 6   
2 0  
2 1  
2 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For these split, apply, combine problems - I like using [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/). There are alternatives if speed becomes an issue, but for most things - plyr is easy to understand and use. I wrote a function that implements the logic you described above and then fed that to `ddply()` to operate on each chunk of the data based on ID.

```
fun <- function(x, column, threshold, numplus){
  whichcol <- which(x[column] > threshold)[1]
  rows <- seq(from = (whichcol + numplus), to = nrow(x))
  return(x[rows,])
}
```

And then feed this to `ddply()`

```
require(plyr)
ddply(dat, "ID", fun, column = "x", threshold = 0, numplus = 5)
#-----
  ID x
1  1 9
2  1 0
3  1 0
4  1 6
5  2 0
6  2 1
7  2 3
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. That was exactly what I was looking for - clean R style solution.